# Custom Nuget package does not add .targets file as import step in csproj file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, nuget, csproj

I have an existing solution in VS2015 with several projects.  We have some referenced dlls that we would like to convert over to nuget packages to avoid checking into the repo.  I have created two packages and placed them in a fileshare on out network.  The packages installs exactly as in my test projects including call for the import of the packages `.targets` file.

Here is the targets file the point of which is to copy unmanaged code dlls:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <NativeLibs Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)**\*.dll" />
    <None Include="@(NativeLibs)">
      <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Which is referenced in the nuspec file like this:

```
<file src="build\win64\native\Some.Amazing.Nuget.Packge.x64.targets" target="build" />
```

And here is what is added to my **test** solution csproj files:

```
</Project>
  .......

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" /> <!-- This was already there-->

  <Import Project="..\packages\Some.Amazing.Nuget.Packge.x64.1.1.1.1\build\Some.Amazing.Nuget.Packge.x64.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Some.Amazing.Nuget.Packge.x64.1.1.1.1\build\Some.Amazing.Nuget.Packge.x64.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Some.Amazing.Nuget.Packge.x64.1.1.1.1\build\Some.Amazing.Nuget.Packge.x64.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Some.Amazing.Nuget.Packge.x64.1.1.1.1\build\Some.Amazing.Nuget.Packge.x64.targets'))" />
  </Target>  
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

So, everything seems to work well.  And I have an x86 version of the package as well.  But either work just fine no matter the platform as for an building go (actually runtime would obviously be another story).

But when I try to pull the same package into the **main** solution projects it is intended for, that `Import` section does not get added to the csproj files.  Which means the additional DLLs are not copied to the bin folders.  I can manually add it but seems like that should be necessary.  Is there a setting I should look out for?

Comment: Should work. Is the main solution have special projects? Such as say using a project.json file?

Comment: @MattWard Thanks for the reply.  No, nothing other then c# libraries, unit tests, and a WPF app.  Nothing requiring anything other the standard install of VS

Comment: Not sure what the problem could be. If you are using a packages.config file with the projects, and the .targets file is named after the package id, which it seems to be, then I would expect an import to be added to the .csproj file. Only other thought is that if the packages.config file already has that package id in there then it would not install it again.

Comment: @ErnieS Did you find out what the problem was in the end?

Comment: @Oliver  It was so long ago I cannot remember exactly, but I do not believe we ever figured it out why.  I think we simply adding the copy commands manually.  We are not using that custom package anymore so I cannot be sure.